# Delete all key offsets from multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

In the below Array  i want to remove only keys i.e [0][1][2]
How to do it.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 147702
            [orders_id] => 832
          )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 147703
            [orders_id] => 832
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 147704
            [orders_id] => 832
        )

)
```

My final output should be

```
Array
(
    Array
        (
            [id] => 147702
            [orders_id] => 832
          )

    Array
        (
            [id] => 147703
            [orders_id] => 832
        )

    Array
        (
            [id] => 147704
            [orders_id] => 832
        )

)
```

Can anyone tell me, how to do this

Comment: You can't do this, if you have an array (or a collection, or whatever) they all have a pointer of some description.

Comment: Thinking about it, your question suggests you're doing /trying to do something you don't understand.  Why do you want to remove the indexes, what are you hoping to do/achieve with the data?

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible because those are array indexes. Every element in the array has its own indexes and will not be deleted anyways.